# Is there a Google Reader Indicator?

Tags: software-recommendation, indicator

Is there a working Google Reader unread feed indicator? Some sort of applet that checks for new unread messages from Google reader and displays their title in a drop down menu or through the notify OSD. Most of the apps I found were either broken or outdated;

- GrNotify isn't updated anymore
- Cloudsn doesn't support Google's 2-step verfication
- Feed Indicator just doesn't work, etc.

PS: I dislike Liferea and Lightread just doesn't work that well as an indicator but is an awesome reader.

Comment: i guess we will have to wait until someone build a reader notifier :(

Comment: Hopefully that would happen soon because it's a becoming a necessity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Google Reader indicator
http://google-reader-indicator.en.uptodown.com/ubuntu
it is excelent app.

Comment: Thank you! I tried the 0.2 version before but it was broken. This version works smoothly!